# Firebase promise react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, es6-promise

I need to get list of files from a specific Firebase storage folder. To access the folder I need to run a firebase Realtime database which provides the folder structure.

Structure of firebase nested folder is like this

images/year/month/day/

In the above folder images are stored. I need to list the data with a downloadable url of the files:

images/2020/jan/1/img1.jpg
images/2020/jan/2/img1.jpg
images/2020/jan/2/img2.jpg
images/2020/jan/10/img.jpg
images/2020/feb/4/img2.jpg
images/2021/jan/2/img2.jpg

My code

```
firebase.database().ref("images").once("value", (userSnapshot) => {
   userSnapshot.forEach(yr => {
        const year = yr.key;
        yr.forEach(mnth => {
          const month = moment(mnth.key, 'MM').format('MMM');
          const mm = mnth.key;
          mnth.forEach(dy => {
            const day = dy.key;
            dy.forEach(element => {
              // Here I need to call the function to list all the files 
                asynchronously
              // after getting files I need to push this to an array with the following data of year, month, date, files
            });
          });
       });
    });
});
```

file list function has the following code:

```
var pref = 'images/'+year+'/'+month+'/'+day+'/'+element+'/';
var listRef = firebase.storage().ref(pref);
res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
                        
var files = itemRef.name;
                        listRef.child(files).getDownloadURL().then(function(fileurl) {
  const furl = fileurl;
  filelist.push({furl});
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle any errors
});
});
})
```